# C# check pattern of a datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have to receive a datetime property through webservice which has two possible formats:

```
2018-05-14T12:20:45:123+02:00

2018-05-14T12:20:45:123Z
```

How can I ask to a datetime variable if the pattern is one or another?

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz

yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ
```

Comment: Have a look at `TryParseExact` with specifying these formats. If it isn't in the format it will return `false`

Comment: A `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format. You can try to parse a *string* as one of those formats (to a `DateTime`) but the `DateTime` value itself doesn't have any concept of a format - just like there's no such thing as a "decimal int" or a "hex int".

Comment: Also, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Take The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) in order to improve your question. You should specify what you have tried to do (show some code) and what you have researched.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a string. I just have a datetime informed through a web service

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParseExact` which will return `bool` - `true` if parse succeed else `false`:

```
bool isPattern1 = DateTime.TryParseExact("yourdate string", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result1);
bool isPattern2 = DateTime.TryParseExact("yourdate string", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result2);

if(isPattern1)
{
    //your code
}

if(isPattern2)
{
    //your code
}
```

OR you can use second overload with `string[]` as formats parameter if you don't need to actually check which pattern worked, but you need to be sure that string was from this two formats:

```
var formats = new [] { "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ" };

bool isParseSucceed = DateTime.TryParseExact("yourdate string", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result);
```

Comment: The second doesn't answer the question which pattern worked, but maybe OP doesn't really need to know it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've just added your comment into my question, thought it will be a little help maybe for other users.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm not saying you downvoted, just answering to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` haven't got any format. What you call format is a *"format of string representation of DateTime"*.

You can parse both values with `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()` - they will work for both.

```
DateTime.Parse("2018-05-14T12:20:45.123+02:00") // [14.05.2018 15:20:45]
DateTime.Parse("2018-05-14T12:20:45.123Z")      // [14.05.2018 15:20:45]
```

To determine wich format you receive from webservice:

```
if (responseDateTimeString.EndsWith("Z"))
    // it's '2018-05-14T12:20:45.123Z' format
else
    // it's not '2018-05-14T12:20:45.123Z' format (it's '2018-05-14T12:20:45.123+02:00')
```